# Is it possible to delete price per item in bundle product?

Tags: bundle

I have some question. We have some gourmet gift boxes which include a few products. The price is a bit higher then when you pick up all the products, so is there an option to remove/hide the price per item? And just to show total price?

Thanks in advance!